# Assembly version vs. Win32 resource version

Tags: c#, resources, version

I'm using a Win32 resource file (`.res`) in one assembly (exe) to provide mutliple icons. The reason is that multiple links points to the exe, using different icons for the each link.

Therefore I changed the project settings in Application > Resources from `Icon` to `Resource File`, providing the `.res` file.

[image]

But now there's the problem that the assembly's version is no longer taken from `AssemblyInfo.cs`, but from the `.res` file. 
When switching the application settings back to `Icon`, the version is again taken from `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

**How can I tell Visual Studio to use still `AssmblyInfo.cs` to use the version from?**

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f2f5x2e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't provide more information on this.

Comment: No, the super-duper important [AssemblyVersion] is most certainly still taken from the AssemblyInfo.cs source file.  Only the other ones, like the *visible* file version number are now maintained by the unmanaged VERSION resource.  Whatever you see back in the Explorer property sheet.   Maintaining it requires editing the VERSION resource, no workaround for that.  Simply to do as long as you keep a dummy C++ project around so the .rc file is easy to edit and the .res file creation is automatic.  That [AssemblyVersion] is not visible in Explorer is a bit of a tragedy.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's ok. But `Application.ProductVersion` doesn't return the version from `AssemblyInfo.cs`. I also have to mention that the `.res` file only have icons, no version resource here.

Comment: Well, omitting VERSION is just a hair shy from a bug.  If you care about Application.ProductVersion then you should use [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("w.x.y.z")] in your AssemblyInfo.cs file.